# TextChangedListener и маска

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Написал форму для проверки региона по номеру телефона
Поставил TextWatcher на форму ввода, он отслеживает значение поля ввода и подставляет маску, вот только если я удаляю значение и пытаюсь ввести номер другого региона то подставляется уже другая маска и вылетает ошибка

> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>                         at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)

Происходит это как я понял из-за того что я пытаюсь присвоить EditText'у две маски, вопрос, как мне удалять предыдущую маску и заменять на новую?

```
editPhone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            if(editPhone.getText().toString().equals("+3")){
                editPhone.addTextChangedListener(new MaskedWatcher("+38 (###) ###-##-##"));
            }
            if(editPhone.getText().toString().equals("+7")){
                editPhone.addTextChangedListener(new MaskedWatcher("+7 (###) ###-##-##"));
            }
            if(editPhone.getText().toString().equals("")){
                editPhone.setText("+");
                editPhone.setSelection(editPhone.getText().length());
            }
            if(editPhone.getText().toString().equals("+1")){
                editPhone.addTextChangedListener(new MaskedWatcher("+1 (###) ###-##-##"));
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackOverflowError  у вас из-за того что вы в onTextChanged еще раз задаете TextWatcher для editPhone. Вам нужно логику в MaskedWatcher поправить. Чтобы внутри этого MaskedWatcher была проверка на тип маски. и сделать изначально нужно editPhone.addTextChangedListener(new MaskedWatcher()). Покажите код new MaskedWatcher для подробного ответа

Comment: https://github.com/VicMikhailau/MaskedEditText/tree/master/MaskedEditText/src/main/java/com/vicmikhailau/maskededittext , это сторонняя библиотека

Comment: Может создать глобально маску и потом через метод setMask() устанавливать новую?

Comment: Да. Вы можете сделать наследника MaskedWatcher, с конструктором без параметра. Или даже можно использовать этот MaskedWatcher с произвольной маской в начале. А на onTextChanged делать setMask нужной маски

Comment: final MaskedWatcher maskedWatcher = new MaskedWatcher(""); maskedWatcher.setMask("+38 (###) ###-##-##"); Верно, вот так заработало